# Select Year as well as Month from Datetime field and Insert into Date field

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have value in field 'DateandTime' as 2015-05-12 12:04:15 and it is stored table1. I have so many values in same month.

I just want to insert it to table2 only year and month in the format '2015-05' and the field type is date and the field name is 'Date'.

How can I do this in mysql? And not in PHP.

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: What code have you tried?  It might be a simple change for something you already have.  If you don't have anything, I'd head over to a search engine and look for mysql substrings, as you're only after a part of what you already have.

Comment: Hi thanks to initiate for problem solving. I tried many ways. For ex, one of them are, "insert into table2 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateandTime,"%Y-%m") as Date from table1 group by month(DateandTime), year(DateandTime);"

Comment: @AGamores It is giving syntax error

Comment: It is not an answer, but why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (edited, see below):

```
-- This query fails
-- insert into table2 values (select distinct(DATE_FORMAT(DateandTime, "%Y-%m")) as yearmonth from table1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Yes, you're right. I write the answer without executing it... Try this, please:

```
insert into table2 select distinct(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DateandTime, "%Y-%m"), '%Y-%m')) from table1
```